# Get started with Crypto++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, crypto++

I don't know if it's right to ask this question here or not.
I'm trying to use Crypto++ library in a project. I can't even get started with it. This is the code I'm trying:

```
#include <cryptlib.h>
#include <sha.h>

int main()
{
    SHA hash;  // ERROR here. can't find SHA
    return 0;
}
```

I tried reading the readme file included in the download package. I tried [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16388/Compiling-and-Integrating-Crypto-into-the-Microsof) and still didn't manage to get it to work. I'm using VS2010.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20071208044702/http://www.trolocsis.com/crypto++/sha_8h-source.html):

```
NAMESPACE_BEGIN(CryptoPP)

class CRYPTOPP_DLL SHA : public ...
```

it appears that `SHA` is a member of namespace `CryptoPP`. Try:

```
CryptoPP::SHA hash;
```

Comment: Thanks. Either it's because I've never used a library before, or this library's documentation sucks.